# QGIS: Create polygon shapefile of ellipses from points using Geometry by expression tool

Tags: qgis, geometry, expression, ellipse

In QGIS 3.16.6 I need to create a polygon shapefile of ellipses from points.  I am doing the following:

Processing Toolbox -> Vector Geometry -> Geometry by expression

- Input layer - points_in.shp
- Output geometry type - polygon
- Geometry expression - `make_ellipse(transform(make_point("Lon-DD","Lat-DD"), 'EPSG:4269', 'EPSG:26913'), 635, 190, 90)`
- Modified geometry - ellipses_out.shp

Where "Lon-DD" and"Lat-DD" are fields in the point shapefile, the input CRS is GDD NAD83, the output CRS NAD83/UTM Zone 13N meters, and the semi-major and semi-minor axis are 635 meters and 190 meters and the azimuth is 90 degrees.

The Geometry by expression tool runs without complaints but the output shapefile is empty.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you check the attribute table of ellipses_out layer? Did you zoom to the layer? Does "Empty" mean that you don't see ellipses in the map or that the attribute table of "ellipses_out" is empty?

Comment: Zooming to the output layer is different than zooming to the input layer.  The output layer is there, all 200 plus ellipses.  So I know what the problem is now what is the solution?  Again, transform('EPSG:4269', 'EPSG:26913') appears not to be working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you expect that `make_ellipse` returns an ellipse in EPSG:26913 coordinates. Yes, it returns EPSG:26913 coordinates (big numbers like `500000` which are projected coordinates), but QGIS considers those are in source layer's CRS, EPSG:4269 (lat, long). If you check the CRS of `ellipses_out`, you will see its CRS is EPSG:4269.

For a solution, use `Processing toolbox > Vector general > Assign projection` tool for output layer. Choose EPSG:26913 as new CRS.

[image]

Comment: Right.  Thanks for identifying the problem, but what I asked was for a solution: "What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?"  Apparently transform('EPSG:4269', 'EPSG:26913') is not working.  I assume that if I project the input points from GDD to UTM first, then this should work?